# Send single response after multiple updates

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have an array of items that I am passing to an API endpoint (using Sequelize as my ORM). I'm trying to iterate over each item and update it, however I'm getting a `Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

```
stepsController.put = (req, res) => {
  const { steps } = req.body;
  // Steps is an array of objects that I want to update...
  steps.map(step => {
    Step.findOne({ where: { id: step.id } })
      .then(savedStep =>
        savedStep
          .update({
            order: step.order,
          })
          .then(success => res.status(200).send(success))
          .catch(error => res.send(error))
      )
      .then(ok => res.status(200).send(ok))
      .catch(err => res.send(err));
  });
};
```

I believe this is because it's sending the response for each item. Sequelize's `update` method is a promise. How can I iterate over all of the items and make sure all of the items are updated before sending a single successful response?

Answer (score 0):

> There are three ways you can do
>
> 1. Promise.all
> 2. Co
> 3. Async Await

---

1) Here it is , you can use `Promise.all` :

```
stepsController.put = (req, res) => {
    const { steps } = req.body;
    // Steps is an array of objects that I want to update...
    Promise.all(steps.map(step => {
        return Step.findOne({ where: { id: step.id } }).then(savedStep =>
                return savedStep.update({
                    order: step.order,
                })
                .catch(error => error)
        ).catch(err => err)
    }))
    .then(ok => res.status(200).send(ok))
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
};
```

---

2) Another way is to use [**co**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) :

```
const co = require('co');

stepsController.put = co.wrap(function* (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { steps } = req.body;
        // Steps is an array of objects that I want to update...  
        for(let i=0;i<steps.length ; i++) {
            let savedStep = yield Step.findOne({ where: { id: steps[i].id } });
            if(savedStep)
                yield savedStep.update({ order: steps[i].order});
        }
        res.status(200).send();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

---

3) If you’re using Node 8.0+ , there is no need of any package you can directly use `async await` :

```
stepsController.put = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { steps } = req.body;
        // Steps is an array of objects that I want to update...  
        for(let i=0;i<steps.length ; i++) {
            let savedStep = await Step.findOne({ where: { id: steps[i].id } });
            if(savedStep)
                await savedStep.update({ order: steps[i].order});
        }
        res.status(200).send();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
};
```